# OpenMP bug in VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, openmp

I did the following minimal example to reproduce a bug I have in VS2017 Community (version 15.9.34, toolset v141) on Windows 10 (SDK 10.0.18362.0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool isFirst = true;

#pragma omp parallel shared(isFirst)
    {
        int values[35];

#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

#pragma omp critical
            {
                if (isFirst) {
                    isFirst = false;
                    std::cout << i << std::endl;
                }
                std::fill_n(values, 35, 3);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

This code strangely outputs:

```
.\minimalBug.exe
3
2
0
1
```

(or any other order).
Of course, I am expecting "isFirst" to be true only once, since it is shared.
And the only bug fixes I found were to either replace the std::cout line by

```
std::cout << i <<" "<<&isFirst << std::endl;
```

in which case I get the following output:

```
.\minimalBug.exe
0 000000111D5CFB00
```

(which correctly says that the first iteration finished first ; but this isn't really an option for me since I actually do not want to cout anything here)

or replaced my `bool isFirst = true;` by `bool isFirst[1] = {true};` and use `isFirst[0]` after that.
The bug also does not occur if I remove the `std::fill_n line` and it also sometimes only shows 3 values "instead of" 4. The build configuration is the default one except for /openmp.

- Did I miss something obvious or is it a Visual Studio bug ?
- Can you reproduce this bug ?
- Does this occur on other VS versions, or other compilers ?

Thanks!

Comment: No problem with g++ on Linux (only one line is output) (of course compiled with OpenMP)

Comment: No problem with Clang 11.0 either. Can you try with `/openmp:llvm` (or `/openmp:experimental` which should give similar results) ?

Comment: Also works fine on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.3.0

Comment: I tested your code on Visual Studio 2022, 2017, 2010 and they all output 0.

Comment: @JérômeRichard oh thanks! with both llvm and experimental the code works...! does it mean my openmp is messed up somewhere ? At some point I noticed that my critical sections were not (always) critical... (though in this case this does not really matter, as I tested with intensive computations in the foor loop such that there is no way for a concurrency issue to happen here)

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT oh, strange then!